# Sencha 2.4.1 - List Not Displaying Items

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to populate a list with static data in store, using Sencha touch 2.4.1.

One main view contains the titlebar and the list. The list is trying to get the data from the store based model, Employee.

Following are the code snippets, I cannot find out where I am getting it wrong.

Employee List View

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.EmpList',{
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'emp_list',
    config:{
         itemTpl: Ext.XTemplate('<span>{firstname}</span>')
    }
});
```

Employee Store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Employee',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config:{
    storeId: 'emp_store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Employee',
    emptyText: 'No Employees Yet!',
    data:[
        {firstname:'Danish', lastname:'Siddiqui', ranking:'1', is_manager:false},
        {firstname:'Danish', lastname:'Siddiqui1', ranking:'2', is_manager:false},
        {firstname:'Danish', lastname:'Siddiqui2', ranking:'3', is_manager:false},
        {firstname:'Danish', lastname:'Siddiqui3', ranking:'4', is_manager:false},
    ]
}

});
```

Employee Model

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Employee',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields:[
        {name: 'firstname',     type:'string'},
        {name: 'lastname',      type:'string'},
        {name: 'ranking',       type:'number'},
        {name: 'is_manager',    type:'boolean', defaultValue: false}
    ]
}
```

});

Main View

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'main',
requires:[
    'Ext.TitleBar'
],
config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Employe Information',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'back',
                    text: 'back'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'emp_list',
            store: 'emp_store'
        }
    ]

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting width and height properties of list works.

```
config:{
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    itemTpl: Ext.XTemplate('<span>{firstname} &nbsp; {lastname}</span>'),
    store: 'emp_store'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Model in employee store should read `'MyApp.model.Employee'`, shouldn't it? If that does not help, see what you get in the store? Is the store loaded with expected records?

Comment: corrected it, still not working, Ext.getStore('Employee') on console gives me undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you had to give your list some size by adding `height` and `width` but also your store won't have loaded in the list due to your reference of an `xtype` rather than an instance of that xtype.
http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-store

So your `Main` view should look like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Employe Information',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: 'back',
                text: 'back'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'emp_list',
            store: Ext.create('MyApp.store.Employee'),
        }]

    }
});
```

and your `EmpList` like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.EmpList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'emp_list',
    config: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        itemTpl: Ext.XTemplate('<span>{firstname}</span>')
    }
});
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gqr

Comment: just giving the store id worked by the way, didn't need to use Ext.create for store. 

I am new to sencha and don't know why it works. I think it binds automatically, and instance is created during the launching phase, if we have listed our store in app.js in stores array ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to load the store and model inside the app.js file

```
stores: ['Employee'],
models: ['Employee']
```

Comment: forgot to mark the right answer before this one, problem was missing height and width attributes.

Comment: ok. good to hear it's solved. I just added this, because your last answer was the Ext.getStore could not find the store.